# How Indoor Navigation works in iOS using iBeacon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I am working on a project that has a requirement of Indoor navigations by using `iBeacon`. Have been searching a lot, I only found some paid sdk and other tools. I know how `iBeacon` used for indoor navigation,but there is some problem. I want move user location first beacon to another but only on specific path,but now when user move than location not follow path as given by me. 
Please let me know. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: IBeacons aren't used for indoor navigation in that way. You can identify whether the user is in range of a beacon but you can't really use them to precisely locate a person to a particular point and so you can't know how they got from one beacon to another. To achieve that sort of precise indoor location you need to use wifi location

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to build an indoor navigation system using beacons, **it is not a trivial exercise**.  Beacons only provide a very small building block needed to create the overall system.  Think of beacons as being a brick used to build a house.  Are you up for building a house from scratch out of a pile of bricks and many other components?

You may be better off using an off-the-shelf SDK, even if it is paid, rather than building this yourself.  If you do want to build it from scratch, there are several components you must build:

1. **Beacon location configuration**: You need a system to register the location of each beacon in latitude/longitude and get this configuration into the mobile app.
2. **Position determination**: Based on detecting the closest beacon(s), you must build a module that determines the position of the user's mobile phone based on the configuration above.
3. **Map rendering engine**
4. **Coordinate system conversion** from the beacon location configuration reference frame to the map coordinate frame.
5. **Wayfinding module**: Based on configured routes on the map, the wayfinding module would determine where to direct the user along these routes to get to a destination.

I worked on a team that built a beacon-based indoor nav system for the Consumer Electronics Show.  **It took multiple team members a few months to build the system from scratch** using hundreds of beacons and low-level tools.  Don't underestimate the effort involved.

Comment: Hi David i am new to develop iBeacon indoor navigation iOS.can you please more clearly describe what i should do.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is assuming that the user will have no other location services (GPS etc), it could be achieved using multiple iBeacons.

1. The all possible routes between the start and end destination would need to have to iBeacons on them.
2. Register that the user has arrived at the first beacon, and display to them your chosen route.
3. If you detect them getting close to any beacons which are not on your chosen route, then you know they're probably not following it.

So with enough beacons, you can accurately plot the user's location in an indoor environment (provided you know the exact location of the iBeacons beforehand).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. let consider this idea inside a office building that multiple cabin exist, & inside of every cabin i placed a beacon.when user move from first cabin to another cabin than  how can i made .

Comment: That's the correct approach I believe. We have done something similar by placing iBeacons at the end of corridors, since people would be forced to pass by close to them.

Also by examining the strength of the beacons (i.e the probable range), you are able to determine roughly what direction the user is moving in.